# MacOS Monetery File Dates are not rendering correctly

Tags: macos, monterey

MacOS Monterey Version: 12.4 (21F79)

So since doing a massive jump in updates, finder is no longer showing dates correctly, all I get is `at`.
Also if I go and "Get Info" on the file you see the same, all the dates show as `at`.

[image: MacOS Finder with Date Columns showing at]
[image: Get Info for a file, showing at as the date]

If I go to the Console App, and look at any of the options with a date, all it shows is a `,`.

[image: Console App showing , as the date]

So now to the things I've tried:

- SMC Reset
- PRMA/NVRAM Rest
- Disk Repair (Disk Utility First-Aid)
- Re-install (without erasing data)

Any and all help will be very much appreciated.

**UPDATE**:
Tried to re-index with spotlight, but no difference

Using the command `GetFileInfo` shows the correct data

```
TEAL-C02ZR0G2MD6W:tmp:$ GetFileInfo com.PM2.err
file: "/private/tmp/com.PM2.err"
type: "\0\0\0\0"
creator: "\0\0\0\0"
attributes: avbstclinmedz
created: 05/17/2022 15:25:09
modified: 05/17/2022 15:25:24
```

Doing a `stat` on the file also shows the correct information:

```
stat com.PM2.err
16777222 170309676 -rw-r--r-- 1 adrianbrowning wheel 0 4006 "May 17 15:25:09 2022" "May 17 15:25:24 2022" "May 17 15:25:24 2022" "May 17 15:25:09 2022" 4096 8 0 com.PM2.err
```

Comment: I’ve got my first Mac installing 12.4 now. Will test. Do you have a common date format selected - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/mac-help/mh27073/mac

Comment: @bmike - Thank you! That was exactly what the issue was. It was set to a "Custom" variant, now it's back to the standard

Comment: If you can answer your question with a screen shot, I’ll vote that up too +1. That picture will help others I am sure know this got answered.

Answer (score 4):

So thanks to @bmike and his suggestion to check the Language & Region settings I found the culprit.

[image: Language & Region Settings]

The Preferred Language was `United Kingdom (Custom)`. With all of the Date fields being empty.

[image: Language & Region Settings > Preferred Language > Advanced > Dates]

After resetting to the default `United Kingdom` settings, and now everything is now back to normal!

Comment: I’ve seen some rumblings that other apps / panels lost settings like this. Do you think you made these changes intentionally or the system dropped these unexpectedly / recently? (Excellent, excellent post - thanks for all the details!)